# How can I unescape a url's host?

Tags: url, go, escaping

I have the following URL I'm trying to process:

```
http://shitenonions%2elibsyn%2ecom/rss
```

When I try to create a url out of it in Go, I get the following error:

```
panic: parse http://shitenonions%2elibsyn%2ecom/rss: hexadecimal escape in host
```

How can I fix this URL so it can be parsed correctly?  I have a large set of URLs and several of them have this problem.

I thought about URL decoding it, but I'm worried that if I do that, it might be incorrect to url decode items besides the host name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `url.QueryUnescape` to decode entities `%hh` back to the characters:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/url"
  "strings"
)

func fixHost(link string) string {
  if strings.HasPrefix(link, "http://") {
    p := strings.Index(link[7:], "/")
    if -1 != p {
      host, _ := url.QueryUnescape(link[7:7+p])
      return "http://" + host + link[7+p:]
    }
  }
  return link
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(fixHost("http://shitenonions%2elibsyn%2ecom/rss"))
}
```